# ACF: update_field using a button

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a button that when clicked I want to add one to the counter. I am using ACF, and came across the update_field function.

Any idea how to do this? I am hoping to do via Ajax or something that once the button is clicked the number increases accordingly without having to refresh the page.

This number needs to be permanent, hence why I want to keep ACF.

Comment: where is the button? At wp-admin or frontend? Is it possible to show some screenshot.

Comment: You're on the good track, use Ajax to pass the `$post_id` to be increased to a PHP file and use `update_field('counter_field', $increased_value, $post_id)` to update it.